# using multiple network interfaces to broadcast fractions of data in each(load-balancing / bonding)

Tags: c#, performance, load-balancing, file-transfer

the question is : 
**how to send data over multiple internet connections avilable on current pc?**

possibly-partially simlilar to [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112109/broadcasting-udp-packets-using-multiple-nics)

though my idea is(like raid-0 is using multiple hdd's , to take advatage of multiple nic's)
actually multiple internet connections/accounts to maximize
the throughoutput of the upload bandwidth (which usually has 1/8 of the total bandwidth)

the concept i am trying to implement is to use the fastest protocol, regardless the data integrity 
so i could send data from one point to the other (having a  "client" part of application to handle the data... check for integrity while putting data back to one piece)
or maybe just use tcp if it does not worth it (handling the integrity in application level to increase speed)

i know there's an existing application Called "Connectify" that calimes to do someting similar,
though my idea was to make something little different and i need to understand the basics 
so i could start this project for testing and development.
...thanks in advance !

Comment: What is your *specific* question?

Answer (score 2):

As a generalization of the approach you will need to take in this case would be to create multiple TCP Clients bound to the individual network adapters in your machine. You can iterate through each of the adapters available, test to make sure that they have a connection to the outside world, then add them to a collection where then for each packet of data you want to transmit, you send the packet out.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f.aspx on how to bind TCPClient to individual IPEndPoints.

Because of the nature of the way TCP operates, you will have to construct essentially a wrapper for each packet of data which also includes an order id to ensure that packets received out of order (which will happen most of the time in this case), can be pieced back together again.

Let me know if you need any more help understanding things.

Comment: thanks  for your help so far, i'll first check the link in your post and start coding, then i'll probably get back here .